# Is there a way to wait for a promise to be resolved during preload before loading the renderer with Electron?

Tags: electron

In my app, I have a preload file that used to expose a bunch of HTML templates as strings to the renderer (with `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld`), that would then be used to dynamically create some DOM elements when needed.

However, for security reasons, I'm switching to `nodeIntegration:false`, which means I now have to open those html files in the main process and then send then to the preload file.

The issue is, since there is seemingly no way to wait for those ipcRenderer.invoke(...) to resolve, when the renderer process build the page, the templates are still undefined.

Does anyone see a clean way to work around this issue ? I dread having to change a piece of my framework I built month ago to make my controllers' constructors work asynchronously.

Thanks for any help and insight provided !

Here is a basic example of what I'm trying to do:

IPChandler.ts

```js
...
ipcMain.handle('get-html-template', (htmlTemplateName: htmlTemplateName) => {
    return fs.readFileSync("./src/renderer/templates/" + htmlTemplateName, {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});
});
...
```

preload.ts

```js
...
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'htmlTemplates',
    {
        hoverContainer:  ipcRenderer.invoke('get-html-template', "framework/hover-container.html"),
        OverlayWindow:  ipcRenderer.invoke('get-html-template', "overlay-windows/overlay-window.html"),
        ...
    }
...
```

mainScript.ts (renderer)

```js
...
export class C_OverlayWindow extends Controller {
    static domTemplate = window.htmlTemplates.OverlayWindow;
...
```

The Controller class' constructor use the domTemplate string to build the DOM element and insert it in the DOM. Please note that this code is NOT working, as the templates exposed in the preload to the render process in the code are Promise instead of string. I would use an await statement, but it is rejected on module's top level.

Comment: can you show an example of what you are trying to do in the main and renderer code?  I think i follow but not quite sure how you are using the HTML templates

Comment: I edited my post to add an example of the code I implemented.